# Transformation of dielctric constant tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, rotation, dielectric

I have a dielectric tensor
$$K = \begin{pmatrix}
2000 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2000 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 50
\end{pmatrix};$$
 which I want to transform to a new coordinate system given by Euler's angles ($\phi = 0.277$, $\theta = 0.804$, $\psi = 0$) in ZXZ system.

For given Euler's angles the transformation matrix comes out to be

$$a = \begin{pmatrix}
 0.961826 & 0.273663 & 0. \\ -0.189707 & 0.666753 & 0.720729 \\ 0.197237 & -0.693216 & 0.693216
\end{pmatrix}.$$
 The transformation rule $K' = a \cdot K \cdot a^T$ is giving negative values of $K'$ components !!

Will appreciate any help.

thanks

Comment: Why do you think it would be a problem, if the transformed
dielectric matrix $K'$ has some negative coefficients?
The important thing is: $K'$ is positive definite again
and has the same eigenvalues ($2000$, $2000$, $50$) as $K$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does it not mean a negative value of dielectric constant in one of the directions ? I am bit confused about it.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a reference to understand it better !!

Comment: You have to ask yourself what $a$ means. It means the same in any coordinate system, so that would answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, but still not sure about it. For example if K11' is negative for Euler's angles (a1, a2, a3), would it mean that if I make a capacitor by rotating the crystal by these Euler's angles, capacitance would be negative ?